# simple NSTimer test not working

Tags: objective-c

Im learning about NSTimer and after reading Docs I made this simple test. My understanding is that when I call viewDidLoad in main, viewDidLoad should then call runTest after 3.0 secs - but it's not working. It compiles fine with no errors but will not load runTest (no NSLog) please help ... thank you.

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

MyClass *trial = [[MyClass alloc]init];

[trial viewDidLoad]; ///// this should call viewDidLoad /////

[pool drain];
return 0;
}



#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject {

NSTimer *aTimer;}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *aTimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad;

- (void)runTest;

@end





#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize aTimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self     selector:@selector(runTest) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];}

- (void) runTest {
NSLog(@"Working - runTest has loaded !");
aTimer = nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 2):

It will not work this way. NSTimer requires a runloop, which will be created automatically when you make a normal Cocoa Application not a Foundation command line tool.

Create the timer in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of the application delegate or in the `init` of your object if you instantiate it in the main nib.

Comment: Are you saying that NSTimer cannot be used in any form when producing small apps for console only ?? if yes, a small example of applicationDidFinishLaunching would be great.

Comment: Just make a new Cocoa Application and go to the AppDelegate class. You will see `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method.